# ¿Cómo se hace para que el cambio de directorio en un script sea permanente?

Tags: bash, unix

Tengo este script para consola en ubuntu 18

```
#!/bin/bash
cd Documentos
cd GuiaAzulDashLinux
source GuiaAzulDashLinux_env/bin/activate
cd GuiaAzulDashLinuxSrc
cdo
python3 manage.py runserver
```

Pero al salir del script, vuelvo al home (~).

¿Cómo se hace para que el cambio de directorio sea permanente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando ejecutas un script, este se ejecuta en una *subshell* y, al terminar, te devuelve a la shell inicial donde estabas.

Por tanto, si tienes un fichero "mi_script.sh":

echo "$pwd"
cd /tmp
echo "$pwd"

Lo que harás al ejecutarlo es moverte a `/tmp` en *esa* subshell y finalmente volverás a tu directorio inicial cuando termine:

```
$ pwd
/home/fedor
$ bash mi_script.sh 
/home/fedor
/tmp
$ pwd
/home/fedor
```

Si lo que quieres hacer es que este script se ejecute en tu shell actual, en lugar de ejecutarlo debes hacer **`source`**:

```
$ pwd
/home/fedor
$ source mi_script.sh  # <-- source!
/home/fedor
/tmp
$ pwd
/tmp.                  # <-- se ha quedado en /tmp!
```

Comment: Te pasaste!, era lo que buscaba!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que cuando ejecutas un comando desde la terminal, lo que en realidad estas haciendo es crear un proceso hijo que ejecuta dicho comando, por tal razón el proceso que se mueve a los directorios que le indicas es el hijo, el padre solamente recibe el mensaje de salida emitido por el proceso hijo.

Puedes hacer la prueba obteniendo el pid del proceso de terminal y el de los hijos que ejecutas de una forma similar a la siguiente:

```sh
$ echo $$;
3502
$ ( echo $$; echo $BASHPID )
3502
4584
$ ( echo $$; echo $BASHPID )
3502
4591
```

Comment: No hay una forma más sencilla poniendo alguna línea dentro del script?

Answer (score 0):

Añade la linea
exec bash
Ejemplo:

```
ruta=$(dialog --title "Selecciona un directorio" \
          --stdout \
      --dselect ~/. 14 70)
cd ${ruta}
clear
echo "Directorio seleccionado: ${ruta}"
exec bash
```

En mi Apple funciona !

Comment: Esta pregunta ya fue respondida hace 5 años, y el autor aceptó la respuesta por válida. Evita reflotar preguntas antiguas si ya fueron solucionadas. Veo que eres un usuario nuevo, echa un ojo a es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @PabloGonzález en [es.so] no existe el concepto de _necrobumping_, por lo tanto es válido responder a preguntas antiguas que incluso cuenten con respuestas aceptadas. Una respuesta _aceptada_ significa que la respuesta le ha sido útil a OP, no necesariamente que es la única respuesta válida a tal pregunta. Lo que sí debe hacer el autor de esta respuesta es pulsar en [edit] y explicar qué hace su código, en base a [answer].